# Is there a way to exclude a specific branch from gitlab AutoDevOps?

Tags: gitlab-ci

I am trying to exclude a specific branch `production` from the gitlab pipeline in AutoDevOps, however I don't seen to be able to figure out the correct syntax.  Here is what I have:

```
build:
  stage: build
  image: docker:19.03.1
  variables:
    DOCKER_TLS_CERTDIR: ""
  services:
    - docker:19.03.8-dind
  before_script:
    - docker login -u "$CI_REGISTRY_USER" -p "$CI_REGISTRY_PASSWORD" $CI_REGISTRY
  script:
    - |
      if [[ -z "$CI_COMMIT_TAG" ]]; then
        export CI_APPLICATION_REPOSITORY=${CI_APPLICATION_REPOSITORY:-$CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE/$CI_COMMIT_REF_SLUG}
        export CI_APPLICATION_TAG=${CI_APPLICATION_TAG:-$CI_COMMIT_SHA}
      else
        export CI_APPLICATION_REPOSITORY=${CI_APPLICATION_REPOSITORY:-$CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE}
        export CI_APPLICATION_TAG=${CI_APPLICATION_TAG:-$CI_COMMIT_TAG}
      fi
    # make and git needed to run makefiles
    - apk add --update make
    - apk add --update git
    - make ci-build
    - make ensure_project publish_artifact
  rules:
    # don't build on production - that is just a marker branch in git
    - if: '$CI_COMMIT_BRANCH != "production"'
    - if: '$CI_COMMIT_TAG || $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH'
```

However, the pipeline still runs for `production`. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3):

Could you try except instead of rules

```
except:
  - production
```

[Gitlab CI/CD Pipeline Configuration](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#onlyexcept-basic)

Comment: No, that doesn't seem to work.  I think it is because the parent build definition in autodevops has a rules defined.  When I do the CI Lint I get this: `jobs:build config key may not be used with rules: except`

Comment: `only/except` is no longer maintained and discouraged since it may be dropped due to deprecation - additionally you cannot use both rules and only/except in the same job

Answer (score 0):

I have solved such task with this

```
    rules:
        - if: '$CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "merge_request_event" && $CI_MERGE_REQUEST_TARGET_BRANCH_NAME =~ /^dev$/'
```